# After failing review test only getting tests and no actual reviews

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I recently failed a review test. I thought a closed question should remain closed, but the test said it should have been re-opened.

Since then every review I've been doing has been a review test. I'm trying to go through the suggested edits review queue, but every single question I get is a test. It's getting tiresome clicking 'invalid edit' or 'radical edit' and then getting told that I passed.

How many of these do I have to pass before I can start reviewing proper suggested edits again?

Comment: Sounds more like a bug to me.